# In Linux how do I get my Perl script to run like a binary?

Tags: linux, perl, symlink

I have a Perl Script that i'd like to be able to run from the command line. I can run this perfectly on it's own. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**Here are the things I've tried**

```
 $ ln -s slice.pl /bin
 $ ln -s slice.pl /usr/bin

 $ ln -s slice.pl /bin/slice
 $ ln -s slice.pl /usr/bin/slice

 $ slice
 $ slice: command not found
```

Does the symlink have to be **chmod +x?** The original file is.

Comment: How other than on its own (which I assume you mean from your shell’s command line) are you trying to run `slice.pl`?

Comment: I want to be able to do `$ slice` rather than `$ /opt/slice/slice.pl`, I am trying to `ln -s /opt/slice/slice.pl /usr/bin/slice`

Comment: Add the output from three commands to the data in your question: (1) `ls -l /bin/slice*`, (2) `ls -lL /bin/slice*`, (3) `sed 1q /bin/slice`.  What happens why you type: `/bin/slice`?  It should be failing the same, but let us make sure.  I hope you've kept a record of all the different names you've created in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` so you can clean up when you've resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to invoke it like this:

```
$ ln -s "`pwd`"/slice.pl /bin/slice
$ slice
```

It fails because the link has to correctly point to the script.

Answer (score 2):

The clue is the `command not found` error. If your shell were finding `slice.pl`, it would have complained about a bad interpreter or a permission error.

Clear your shell’s cache of PATH lookups. With `bash`, run

```
$ hash -r
```

or with C shell derivatives (*e.g.*, `tcsh`), run

```
% rehash
```

After this, you will be able to run your `slice` command.

Associations with file extensions is a DOS-ish convention. With Unix, call your program what it is, *i.e.*, `slice`, and give the program a shebang line (`#!`) to tell the operating system how to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that /bin or /usr/bin/ is in the users $PATH
2. Do a `chmod a+rx slice.pl`
3. Make sure this is the first like in your script

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   ```

   Provided that, it is indeed path to perl. `which perl` will give you the path to a `perl`.
4. Make sure the file uses unix line endings (0A) rather than Windows line endings (0D 0A), especially on the shebang (`#!`) line.

Comment: $which perl: /usr/bin/perl

Comment: shebang: #!/usr/bin/perl

Comment: The script needs to be readable by those that will execute it. Fixed in answer.

Comment: Note that `script.pl`'s directory needs to be accessible (`chmod a+x`) by everyone that is to be allowed to execute it, and so its parent directory and so on until the root.

Comment: @ikegami OP would have gotten a permission-denied error if the issue were read permission.

Comment: I dont think its a permission error. Do you see anything wrong with this? `ln -s slicer.pl /usr/bin/slic3r` Im running as root at the moment and $PATH has /usr/bin within it.